# Select records where id does not equal to x

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have these tables

```
object BooksAuthors : Table(name = "books_authors") {
    val book = reference("book_id", Books, onDelete = ReferenceOption.CASCADE)
    val author = reference("author_id", Authors, onDelete = ReferenceOption.CASCADE)
}

object Books : IntIdTable() {
    val title = varchar("title", 250)
    val isbn = varchar("isbn", 13)
}

object Authors : IntIdTable() {
    val email = varchar("email", 100).uniqueIndex()
}
```

i would like to write a query that returns all books that dont have a specific author so i wrote this

```
suspend fun getBooksWithoutAuthorId(authorId: Int): List<BookDTO> = DbFactory.dbQuery {
    val query = BooksAuthors.innerJoin(Books).select { BooksAuthors.author neq authorId }
    Book.wrapRows(query).map { it.toDTO() }
}
```

But the query returns books that have the author.  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you [checked the generated SQL](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/FAQ#q-how-to-get-a-plain-sql-query-which-will-be-executed)?

Answer (score 3):

As [Sebastian Redl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8922/sebastian-redl) mentioned, there could be books with multiple authors and your query doesn't cover that case.

Correct Exposed query should be:

```kotlin
val query = Books.select {
    Books.id notInSubQuery 
            BooksAuthors.slice(BooksAuthors.book).select { BooksAuthors.author eq authorId }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an n:m mapping where a book can have multiple authors.

Your query, as written, finds any book that an author other than your selected one has authored.

This means if authors Alice and Bob wrote a book together, and you want to find books "not by Bob", you would still find the book because Alice took part.

Your desired query cannot be expressed as a simple join; you need nested queries instead.

Something like equivalent to this SQL:

```
SELECT * from books b WHERE ? NOT IN (
  SELECT ab.author_id FROM authors_books ab WHERE ab.book_id = b.id);
```

Though I'm afraid I don't know how to express this in Exposed.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7BsVUW95g6L4rXDBCoaXK3/0

Comment: thank you for getting back to me so quickly!!!! this is great, i was pulling my hair out